# Load sparse array from npy file

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-array

I am trying load a sparse array that I have previously saved.  Saving the sparse array was easy enough.  Trying to read it though is a pain.  scipy.load returns a 0d array around my sparse array.

```
import scipy as sp
A = sp.load("my_array"); A
array(<325729x325729 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int8'>'
with 1497134 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

In order to get a sparse matrix I have to flatten the 0d array, or use sp.asarray(A).  This seems like a really hard way to do things.  Is Scipy smart enough to understand that it has loaded a sparse array?  Is there a better way to load a sparse array?

Answer (score 15):

The [mmwrite](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmwrite.html#scipy.io.mmwrite)/[mmread](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmread.html#scipy.io.mmread) functions in scipy.io  can save/load sparse matrices in the Matrix Market format.

```
scipy.io.mmwrite('/tmp/my_array',x)
scipy.io.mmread('/tmp/my_array').tolil()
```

`mmwrite` and `mmread` may be all you need. It is well-tested and uses a well-known format.

However, the following might be a bit faster:

We can save the the row and column coordinates and data as 1-d arrays in npz format.

```
import random
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import scipy.io
import numpy as np

def save_sparse_matrix(filename,x):
    x_coo=x.tocoo()
    row=x_coo.row
    col=x_coo.col
    data=x_coo.data
    shape=x_coo.shape
    np.savez(filename,row=row,col=col,data=data,shape=shape)

def load_sparse_matrix(filename):
    y=np.load(filename)
    z=sparse.coo_matrix((y['data'],(y['row'],y['col'])),shape=y['shape'])
    return z

N=20000
x = sparse.lil_matrix( (N,N) )
for i in xrange(N):
    x[random.randint(0,N-1),random.randint(0,N-1)]=random.randint(1,100)

save_sparse_matrix('/tmp/my_array',x)
load_sparse_matrix('/tmp/my_array.npz').tolil()
```

Here is some code which suggests saving the sparse matrix in an npz file 
may be quicker than using mmwrite/mmread:

```
def using_np_savez():    
    save_sparse_matrix('/tmp/my_array',x)
    return load_sparse_matrix('/tmp/my_array.npz').tolil()

def using_mm():
    scipy.io.mmwrite('/tmp/my_array',x)
    return scipy.io.mmread('/tmp/my_array').tolil()    

if __name__=='__main__':
    for func in (using_np_savez,using_mm):
        y=func()
        print(repr(y))
        assert(x.shape==y.shape)
        assert(x.dtype==y.dtype)
        assert(x.__class__==y.__class__)    
        assert(np.allclose(x.todense(),y.todense()))
```

yields

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_mm()'
10 loops, best of 3: 380 msec per loop

% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_np_savez()'
10 loops, best of 3: 116 msec per loop
```

Comment: +1, `scipy.io` is the proper solution. I would add that if you want to go down the optimization road, you might consider `numpy.load(mmap_mode='r'/'c')`. Memory-mapping the files from disk gives instant load **and** can save memory, as the same memory-mapped array can be shared across multiple processes.

Comment: scipy.io.savemat is probably the best

Comment: Using np_savez instead of mm decreased my loading time of a big sparse matrix from 8min47 to 3s ! Thanks ! I also tried savez_compressed but the size is the same and the loading time much longer.

Answer (score 6):

One can extract the object hidden away in the 0d array using () as index:

```
A = sp.load("my_array")[()]
```

This looks weird, but it seems to work anyway, and it is a very short workaround.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can also use .item(), but don't quote me on that :)

Answer (score 1):

For all the up votes of the `mmwrite` answer, I'm surprised no one tried to answer the actual question.   But since it has been reactivated, I'll give it a try.

This reproduces the OP case:

```
In [90]: x=sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(10).reshape(2,5))
In [91]: np.save('save_sparse.npy',x)
In [92]: X=np.load('save_sparse.npy')
In [95]: X
Out[95]: 
array(<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
In [96]: X[()].A
Out[96]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [93]: X[()].A
Out[93]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
In [94]: x
Out[94]: 
<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format
```

The `[()]` that `user4713166 gave us is not a 'hard way' to extract the sparse array.

`np.save` and `np.load` are designed to operate on ndarrays.  But a sparse matrix is not such an array, nor is it a subclass (as `np.matrix` is).  It appears that `np.save` wraps the non-array object in an `object dtype array`, and saves it along with a pickled form of the object.

When I try to save a different kind of object, one that can't be pickled, I get an error message at:

```
403  # We contain Python objects so we cannot write out the data directly.
404  # Instead, we will pickle it out with version 2 of the pickle protocol.
```

--> 405  pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=2)

So in answer to `Is Scipy smart enough to understand that it has loaded a sparse array?`, no. `np.load` does not know about sparse arrays.  But `np.save` is smart enough to punt when given something that isn't an array, and `np.load` does what it can with what if finds in the file.

As to alternative methods of saving and loading sparse arrays, the `io.savemat`, MATLAB compatible method, has been mentioned.  It would be my first choice.  But this example also shows that you can use the regular Python `pickling`.  That might be better if you need to save a particular sparse format.  And `np.save` isn't bad if you can live with the `[()]` extraction step. :)

---

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py
`write_sparse` - sparse are saved in `csc` format.  Along with headers it saves `A.indices.astype('i4'))`, `A.indptr.astype('i4'))`, `A.data.real`, and optionally `A.data.imag`.

---

In quick tests I find that `np.save/load` handles all sparse formats, except `dok`, where the `load` complains about a missing `shape`.  Otherwise I'm not finding any special pickling code in the sparse files.